# Can't load twitter share button via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter

I have a div that I want to load the twitter share button into via jQuery. The works when the script is executed on page load. But after that when I do it manually the script doesn't seem to loaded.

Original button:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="givestreamuk">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I tried just loading the whole button (link plus script) via jQuery but it didn't work, I just got the link. Instead I've tried to inject the script into the DOM like this:

Here's my JS:

```
var twitter = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://customer-url" data-via="givestreamuk" data-hashtags="socialgiving">Tweet</a>';
jQuery('#twitter_share').html(twitter);

var jstext = '!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");';

var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = jstext;
jQuery('#twitter_share').append(script);
```

My DIV the button gets placed in:

```
<div id="twitter_share"></div>
```

This works when the script is executed on page load but then manually after that only the link appears in the div.

Can anyone suggest how I can manually load this button into a DIV and have the script execute so the button gets generated?

Comment: in case anyone's asking why I want to do this. I need to change ```data-url="http://customer-url"``` every time it's loaded...

Comment: Just ran this code in JSFiddle. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qtkdH/

Comment: @JonnyBurger yeah you're right. hmm. Something must be interfering somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Turbolinks, PJAX, or other similar gems in your project?  If so, refer to this thread:

```
https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/25
```

And these solutions:

```
http://www.blackfishweb.com/blog/asynchronously-loading-twitter-google-facebook-and-linkedin-buttons-and-widgets-ajax-bonus

http://reed.github.com/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting content dinamically the Twitter script must be modified, as only the first widget will load correctly.

For new Twitter buttons a script tag with ID `twitter-wjs` already exists and the `if(!d.getElementById(id))` will return `false`.

Just add an `else` statement to that `if` in order to force Twitter Widget object to detect new elements:

```
<script>
!function(d,s,id)
{
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';

    if(!d.getElementById(id))
    {
       js=d.createElement(s);
       js.id=id;
       js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
       js.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
    else
    {
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization